# Calling a EditText field into focus

Tags: android, onclick, imageview, android-edittext, visible

I have a  `EditText` that I have set to invisible by default. I would like to make this box visible `onclick of a ImageView`, but cant find any documentation online to help me, how would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your xml

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/my_edit_text"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:inputType="number"

    android:visibility="gone"

    android:paddingRight="8dp" />
```

In your Activity Class

```
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class MyActivity extends Activity {

    private EditText editTxt = null;
    private Button myBtn = null;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {

        super.onCreate(icicle);
        setContentView(R.layout.my_xml_layout);

        editTxt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.my_edit_text);

        myBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.my_button);
        myBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                editTxt.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Comment: hmmm im pretty sure this is the answer im looking for, but i seem to be getting a couple of weird class errors..."EditText cannot be resolved to a type" and after (new OnClickListener(){ its telling me to enter multiple more markers

Comment: @Adil Sommoro: Thanks bro. Nice to meed you. I am also from township.

Answer (score 0):

well instead of invisible you can make it disable. This way you can prevent it from user input. And it is very easy to enable or disable EditTex.

Answer (score 0):

You can use JQuery to toggle display (display:none vs. display:block) on your EditText field. You probably want to start out with display:none on the EditTextBox. You will also need to have JQuery loaded in your page. Can't make it a detailed tutorial here so giving you enough to get to next level.

```
$jq(document).ready(function() {
  $jq("#yourImageView").click(function(e) {
     $jq("#yourEditTextBox").fadeToggle("slow", "linear");
});
```